Conditionally swallow comma in constructor initializer list macro
I have the following macros that conditionally generate and initialize a member for classes:
#ifdef LIFETIME_TRACKING

#define DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER() mutable ::LifetimeTracker m_tracker
#define INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(x) m_tracker(x)

#else

#define DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER() using dummy = void
#define INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(x) /* ??? */ 

#endif

They are meant to be used as follows:
struct Example
{
    int data;
    Dependency dep;
    DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER();

    Example() : data(42), INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(dep) { }
};

When LIFETIME_TRACKING is defined, everything is fine. When it is not defined, I could not figure out a way of making the constructor initializer list compile the , INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(dep) syntax without either artificially increasing the class's size or making the syntax ugly and not friendly for clang-format (e.g. including the comma inside the macro, as INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(, dep)).
The best I came up with is to have DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER create a dummy empty-struct member:
#define DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER() struct { } m_tracker
#define INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER m_tracker{}

However that increases the size of the parent class.
Is there any way I can keep the desired syntax and not incur a class size increase?

Your snippet is using raw pointers, which is a big NoNo. Using macros is another design red flag. Underscored identifiers are reserved for platform specific use and should not apear in user code. There's not enough information in the post showing how the class is going to be used. But since pointers are usually used as resource handles, your program is most probably violating rule 350 for RAII. You should probably define dependency as a smart pointer type with conditional definitions - instead of using raw pointers and trying to externally track them.

What if your macro would always define another constructor. And then you should call this constructor instead of initializer list. In case your macro defines member then this constructor initialize it. If your macro does not define member then this constructor would have one unused parameter.

If C++17 is not a firm requirement and using C++20 is feasible, you could maybe use [[no_unique_address]], and you would not incur any size penalty by adding a dummy struct

Or you could leverage CRTP to inject the tracking behaviour, instead of adding a member. Because CRTP uses inheritance, empty base class optimization would be guaranteed.

@Red.Wave: frankly speaking, you have no clue what you're talking about. 1. this snippet is a simplified version of a larger real project that focuses on the macro syntax aspect. 2. Raw pointers are totally fine if they don't imply ownership, and sometimes even if they do. There are tradeoffs. 3. Macros are the only way to achieve decent syntax for some things even in C++23. I know exactly what I am doing with the ownership/lifetime model of my classes and my program is not violating rule of 3/5/0. Your only valid point is about _, which is a minor and quick fix.

@dummy: unfortunately I need to add to existing constructors, not add new ones.

@NebularNoise: I had considered that, but I have a strict C++17 requirement.

You knowing about the problem is not going to make the question clear to rest of us. We can not guess what's on your mind if you don't open up about it. But again using a custom smart pointer follows the principle of separation of concerns; it doesn't have to be an owning pointer. You can still encapsulate your dependency pointer into a template with default trait parameter. Each trait class can exploit a different strategy.

@Red.Wave It was a simple question and you came out quoting the sacred rules of C++ in bold and saying raw pointers are bad (they're not) and completely ignored the actual problem at hand

@RedOrav if it were simple, it wouldn't be asked. "The problem at hand" is not clear enough to me. And since last comment by OP, I guess a better alternative to the OP snippet is available.

@Red.Wave "if it were simple, it wouldn't be asked" the question can be simple and the answer complicated. If the problem wasn't clear ask for clarification. As it was, the comment was preachy and unhelpful

@RedOrav what I saw didn't reflect enough details. From my point of view, the code needed to be improved in multiple areas. Nobody can be forced to follow good practice, but I can point the potential pitfalls when I see them. I can't make assumptions about the writer's competence; what I see is the question, and the code sample within.

@VittorioRomeo My thinking isn't fully-baked enough to propose a full answer so I'm commenting: do the C++ member initialization rules allow you to mix "in-place" initializers on members with member-initializer lists? Could "DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER" include its specific initialization, such that you wouldn't need "INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER" at all?

What about simply moving the comma into the macro itself?
#ifdef LIFETIME_TRACKING

#define DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER() mutable ::LifetimeTracker m_tracker;
#define INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(x) ,m_tracker(x)

#else

#define DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER()
#define INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(x)

#endif

struct Example
{
    int data;
    Dependency dep;
    DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER()

    Example() : data(42) INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(dep) { }
};


This is almost acceptable but data(42) INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER(dep) looks quite weird/unusual and breaks automatic formatting. I'm trying to make this change as appetible as possible as it's a submission for an open-source project with strict maintainers, so any "weirdness" is going to cause friction.

"any weirdness is going to cause friction" - Welcome to the wide world of macros. There is no way for the C++ language to swallow the comma if INITIALIZE_TRACKER_MEMBER() doesn't produce something to follow the comma, so you would have to move the comma into a macro so it can be eliminated when needed. Otherwise you are stuck having to initialize a dummy member.

I was hoping there was some weird corner of the language where either (1) some member-like entity can be produced that swallows the comma but does not increase the class size or (2) some syntactical element could be produced in the initializer list only that swallows the comma. But maybe there's nothing here :(

I see 2 possible alternative syntaxes:
struct Example
{
    int data;
    Dependency dep;
    DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER(dep); // Only one initialization

    Example() : data(42) { }
};

with
#ifdef LIFETIME_TRACKING
# define DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER(dep) mutable ::LifetimeTracker m_tracker = dep
#else
# define DEFINE_TRACKER_MEMBER() using dummy = void
#endif

or, a more complex one if Dependencies are members:
struct Example : 
    private boost::base_from_member<Dependency>, // Needed if dependency is a member
    public TRACKER_BASE
{
    int data;

    Example() : TRACKER_BASE(member /* it is dep */), data(42) {}

    // Non-member dependency would be natural
    // Example(Dependency& dep) : TRACKER_BASE(dep) {}
};

with
struct TRACKER_BASE
{
    template <typename T>
    TRACKER_BASE(T&& arg) // or possibly TRACKER_BASE(Depency& arg)
#ifdef LIFETIME_TRACKING
    : m_tracker(std::forward<T>(arg)) {}
    mutable ::LifetimeTracker m_tracker;
else
    {}
#endif

};

and rely on EBO (Empty Base Optimization)
C++20 would allow to have attribute [[unique_address]] to replace EBO, but then you depend on compiler support.
